# How do I fix a permalink that keeps adding an extra part on the end and leading to a 404 error page?

Tags: permalinks, 404-error

I have a permalink that looks perfect but when it's clicked on, it adds an extra section to the link and takes you to 404 page not found. I don't know why this is happening or how to stop it.

This is the url in hover state and as seen in the back end of the site: https://masterflow.net.au/product/automatic-refill-units/

This is the url in the search bar after you click on it:
https://masterflow.net.au/product/automatic-refill-units-masterflow-solutions/

I've tried:

- Retyping the permalink in the back end of the site and updating (no change)
- Typing in the exact permalink according to the search bar (it added the bit on the end again)
- Previewing the page (it came up perfectly, but then I opened the actual page and it still went to 404 error)

Any thoughts on what to do?

Comment: have a look in your `.htaccess` for the text `masterflow-solutions` - there might be something in there that's doing a rewrite or redirect.

Comment: thx that helped!